# MeteorJS unexpected behaviour when calling server methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, gridfs, collectionfs

Some how sequence or delay on server calls brings different behaviour. Code should explain this more clearly.

```
let editProfile = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let info = {};
  info.username = $(".editProfile #usernameInput").val();
  info.email = $(".editProfile #emailInput").val();

  let picture = $(".editProfile #imageInput")[0].files[0]; 
  if (picture) {                               <-|
    Images.insert(picture);                      |Problem
  }                                              |
  Meteor.call("editProfile", this, info);      <-|
};
```

this works fine but when I try to change the sequence of these calls I get error in the console.

```
  Meteor.call("editProfile", this, info);      <-|
  if (picture) {                                 |Error is given
    Images.insert(picture);                      |
  }                                            <-|
```

Error in browser:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> Error: "Queue" failed [404] Not Found [404] [undefined], Error: failed [404] Not Found [404] [undefined]
>       at cfs_upload-http.js:351
>       at cfs_upload-http.js:77
>       at underscore.js:750
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (cfs_upload-http.js:200)

If I try to do something like this: (no error is given)

```
Meteor.call("editProfile", this, info);
setTimeout(function () {
  if (picture) {
    Images.insert(picture);
  }
},2000);
```

I would really like to know why this behaviour is affected by timeouts/sequence.